# DISTINCT but not really

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have table similar to the following:

```
data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | important data
______________________________________________
res1  | res1  | res1  | res1  | NULL         
res2  | res2  | res2  | res2  | NULL         
res2  | res2  | res2  | res2  | wow         
res3  | res3  | res3  | res3  | NULL         
res4  | res4  | res4  | res4  | wow
```

I'd like it to return something like this:

```
data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | important data
______________________________________________
res1  | res1  | res1  | res1  | NULL               
res2  | res2  | res2  | res2  | wow         
res3  | res3  | res3  | res3  | NULL         
res4  | res4  | res4  | res4  | wow
```

so choose distinct(data1, data2, data3, data4) but if such quadruple exist for both NULL and wow, choose always wow.
Is there a way to specify which rows does DISTINCT eliminate?

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify what exactly you're trying to achieve. Your example seems to simply remove a certain row because one column is NULL, whhy do you remove `res2` instead of `res1`?

Comment: you show an example duplicate quadruple with NULL and wow; what if it is NULL, wow, and skycraft?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use aggregation with `max()` (or `min()`) here, since `NULL`s aren't greater than, nor equal, nor less than any other value.

```
SELECT data1,
       data2,
       data3,
       data4,
       max(importantdata) AS importantdata
       FROM elbat
       GROUP BY data1,
                data2,
                data3,
                data4;
```